# templates call other blocks method - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

We can define templates and block in layout file, after that we can call block methods in that template file.

My question is

Is there any way to call **other block methods** in phtml file(template file)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call otherblock method inside any template file using below code,

You can pass here your block, instead of **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct**

```
      $imageBlock =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
      $product=$this->getProducts();
      $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'category_page_list');
```