# Magento 2 get gallery images

Tags: magento2, object, gallery-image

I'm trying to pull through the gallery images on the product page as I'm re doing the gallery. The code I'm using is:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $gallery = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>

<?php foreach ($gallery as $galleries): ?>
  <figure><?php echo $galleries ?></figure>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But this throughs back an error of "Object can't be converted to string"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

override the below template for getting gallery images url in product detail page

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ $json=$block->getGalleryImagesJson();
$array = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $imgurl = $item['full'];
    echo $imgurl;        
}
```

use this above method I rendered full image. you can able to get full,small,thumbnail images. If you want to know about what are the images type available, just var_dump($json).

Comment: How do I get this to work on a custom.phtml page? as the Json returns Null?

Comment: I can't get you clearly what you ask. do you mean place the above script in other phtml?

Comment: yes. One that doesn't already exist so a new .phtml page that I will create an xml block for

Comment: simply change the first line enough :-) $json = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery')->getGalleryImagesJson();

Comment: refer this link for how to call other blocks methods in template file :-) http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116022/templates-call-other-blocks-method-magento-2

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow code for display product images on product detail page.

Add code to **gallary.phtml**

```
<?php
foreach($block->getGalleryImages() as $image){ ?>
    <?php if(!$block->isMainImage($image)):?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image->getData('medium_image_url') ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: How do I get this to work on a custom.phtml as the foreach argument comes back with "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" ?

Comment: Yes if you want to get in your custom.phtml then you have to call block "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery" for you cusotm.phtml and check it. i am not sure but try with this.